# Use odo to load csv file to MySql, get error: Column names of incoming data don't match column names of existing SQL table

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, odo

```
ValueError: Column names of incoming data don't match column names of existing SQL table <br/>
```

Names in SQL table: `['id', 'variable_code', 'zcta', 'value', 'Year']` 
Names from incoming data: `['variable_code', 'zcta', 'value', 'Year']`

The problem is the `'id'` column in SQL table. It will automatically increment. If I read `csv` to DataFrame `df`, then use `df.to_sql()`, it will not get this error. But the speed is super low. I can also add `'id'` column to `csv` file, but I need to read `csv` file to DataFrame, then add `id` column, and then save it to `csv` file. Is there a simple way to solve this problem?

Another problem is: I have some `nan`, `inf` and `-inf` in `'value'` column. If I use `odo`, I get the following error: `Unknown column 'nan' in 'field list'`. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution regarding the 'id' column?

Comment: I didn't solve this problem, how about you?

Comment: I didn't find a solution. I didn't use odo because of this.